# Infinite loop when printing an N x N table

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Consider the following Java program:

```
public class RelativelyPrime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Dimensions of grid
        int i, j;
        int r; // Remainder when i is divided by j

        for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
                do { // Using Euclidean algorithm
                   r = i % j;
                   i = j;
                   j = r;
                } while (r > 0);
                if (i == 1) System.out.print("*");
                else System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints an N x N table (or matrix, if you like) where N is a command-line argument.
The (i, j)-entry is a `*` if i and j are relatively prime, or a single whitespace if they are not relatively prime. When I run the program by entering, for instance, `java RelativelyPrime 3` it endlessly prints `*`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where using the debugger would have helped you solve the problem.

Inside your loops, you alter both `i` and `j` which means they never reach `N` and thus you have an infinite loop.

I suggest you not alter these variables but instead use two new variables, ideally with meaningful names.

Answer (score 3):

You changed `i` and `j` in the while loop.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
            int ii = i, jj = j;
            do { // Using Euclidean algorithm
               r = ii % jj;
               ii = jj;
               jj = r;
            } while (r > 0);
            if (ii == 1) System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```